# How to add objects in a NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I have an app that uses MKMapView. In my app, I have declared an array that will hold the response from the API. The data from the API are the jobs to be pinned in the map (clustered annotations). The array that holds the jobs from the API will/needs to be filtered by the jobs pins that are visible in the map. I am able to filter the coordinates (visible or not visible in the map) but I am having troubles on storing the data (coordinates that are visible) in a new array.

Here's what I have so far:
In regionDidChangeAnimated in my mapview

```
        [ar objectAtIndex:0];
        NSMutableDictionary *visibleJobs;

        for(NSDictionary *loc in ar)
        {
            CLLocationDegrees Lat = [[[loc objectForKey:@"sub_slots"] objectForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue];
            CLLocationDegrees longTitude = [[[loc objectForKey:@"sub_slots"] objectForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue];
            CLLocationCoordinate2D point = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(Lat, longTitude);

            MKMapPoint mkPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(point);

            BOOL contains = MKMapRectContainsPoint(mapView.visibleMapRect, mkPoint);
            if(contains)
            {
                NSLog(@"Contains:1");
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Contains:0");
            }
        }
```

Any help will be very much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't look like you're actually adding anything to the `visibleJobs` array anywhere in your loop. Are you intending to? (Also you declare but do not initialize that variable to point to an array object). You need to be more explicit about what you are expecting to achieve and what behavior you are seeing instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add object to NSMutableArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480473/how-to-add-object-to-nsmutablearray)

Comment: I guess you are trying to add object to an array and not to dictionary but you have taken `NSMutableDictionary *visibleJobs` which is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you use NSMutableArray

try this

```
NSMutableArray *visibleJobs = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for(NSDictionary *loc in ar)
    {
        CLLocationDegrees Lat = [[[loc objectForKey:@"sub_slots"] objectForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue];
        CLLocationDegrees longTitude = [[[loc objectForKey:@"sub_slots"] objectForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D point = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(Lat, longTitude);

        MKMapPoint mkPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(point);

        BOOL contains = MKMapRectContainsPoint(mapView.visibleMapRect, mkPoint);
        if(contains)
        {
            NSLog(@"Contains:1");
            [visibleJobs addObject:loc];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Contains:0");
        }
    }
```

Now visible jobs array contains dictionary of all pin data which in currently visible on map

Comment: dang, i forgot to initialize the array that's why i keep getting a null return value when i am logging the array.. :) thanks, @Malav Soni

Comment: i am still lacking reputation points so i am unable to vote up your answer..thanks anyway.. :)