# how to print only kulumanali and delhi in mutable array?

Tags: objective-c

```
NSArray *cities= [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"hyd",@"bomby",@"delhi", nil];
    NSArray *places= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:cities,@"ooti",@"kulumanal", nil];
    NSMutableArray *citiPlaces= [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"banglore",nil];
```

Comment: Please explain the question in details. also you need to check http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Use **AddObject** to add new object in MutableArray

Comment: What do you mean "print"? There is only Banglore in your mutable Array. Do you mean "append" by print? If yes, [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480473/how-to-add-object-to-nsmutablearray) answers it.

Comment: please elaborate ur question

Comment: U need to append kulumanali and delhi to mutable array ?
U need result like this 
MutableArray (
    banglore,
    kulumanal,
    delhi
)
??

Answer (score -1):

I assume that you want to print kulumanali and delhi from the given arrays. This can be done as:

```
 NSLog(@"%@", [cities objectAtIndexedSubscript:2]);
 NSLog(@"%@", [places objectAtIndexedSubscript:1]);
```

The first line will print delhi and the second one will print kulumanali in the log.

Comment: Don't assume! Ask for clarification and afterwards flag it or answer it depending on the nature of info provided by OP

Comment: That was an expression, OP has clearly mentioned 'how to print', there was no reason to down vote.